# Numpy indexing with ndarray and PyTorch tensor

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, numpy-ndarray

I find numpy array indexing works differently with ndarrray and PyTorch tensor of shape `(1,)` and want to know why. Please see the case below:

```py
import numpy as np
import torch as th

x = np.arange(10)

y = x[np.array([1])]
z = x[th.tensor([1])]
print(y, z)
```

`y` would be `array[2]` while `z` being just `2`. What is the difference exactly?

Comment: @sush ChatGPT isn’t exactly trustworthy in this regard. It gets something’s correct and a lot of things wrong and it’s equally confident in all cases. It’s the drunk guy at a bar who would never admit that they don’t know something and will make up anything to maintain the charade.

Comment: What does `np.array(th.tensor([1]))` do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that integer tensors of a single element can be converted to an index:

```
>>> torch.tensor([1]).__index__()
1
>>> torch.tensor([1, 2]).__index__()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: only integer tensors of a single element can be converted to an index
```

When the index passed in is tensor, `ndarray` cannot recognize it, so it attempts to call its `__index__` method. If the conversion is successful, it is treated as an integer:

```c
if (PyLong_CheckExact(obj) || !PyArray_Check(obj)) {
    // it calls PyNumber_Index() internally
    npy_intp ind = PyArray_PyIntAsIntp(obj);

    if (error_converting(ind)) {
        PyErr_Clear();
    }
    else {
        index_type |= HAS_INTEGER;
        indices[curr_idx].object = NULL;
        indices[curr_idx].value = ind;
        indices[curr_idx].type = HAS_INTEGER;
        used_ndim += 1;
        new_ndim += 0;
        curr_idx += 1;
        continue;
    }
}
```

<sub>[Source code from NumPy.](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/_core/src/multiarray/mapping.c#L388-L404)</sub>

Therefore, the effect of code of OP is equivalent to the following code:

```
>>> np.arange(10)[1]
1
```